# SQL creates new row when I run an update command

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I have this script (below), which is meant to update a value for a specific row in a table. I am searching by ID, which is set as an auto-incrementing, primary key integer. When I run this script, the row is not updated- instead, a completely new row is created.

Here's the code:

```
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$id = $_POST['id'];
$certLevel = $_POST['certlevel'];

$sql = "UPDATE jcontact SET certlevel='$certLevel' WHERE id=$'id'";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close();
```

Comment: why you use like `id=$'id'` ?

Comment: Well look at `$'id'`. This is a great example of why you should stop using `mysql_*` functions and update to `mysqli` or `PDO` and use prepared/paramatized statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think its time to travel from MySQL into MySQLi or PDO.

Second, you need to use `'` for strings and your mistake in your WHERE clause:

`id=$'id'`

You can easily use like this:

`id=$id`

or:

`id='$id'`

Answer (score 1):

Replace this :

```
$sql = "UPDATE jcontact SET certlevel='$certLevel' WHERE id=$'id'";
```

With this :

```
$sql = "UPDATE jcontact SET certlevel='$certLevel' WHERE id='$id'";
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. Any other possible changes?

Comment: Also, the ID is a number

Comment: Write your query in `phpmyadmin` and see what happen.

Comment: Then please provide your complete code. I mean from where do you call this script (e.g HTML).

Comment: <form action="connect.php" method="post" />
<p>Judge ID: <input type="number" name="id" /></p>
<p>Certification Level: <input type="text" name="certlevel" /></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

Comment: Everything looks perfect. You have to debug you code line by line.